# Shrinking dataframe randomly in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of 70.000 rows which I want to reduce to 10.000. I know the cost is huge data loss, but I have my reasons.
I want the cut-down to be evenly distributed throughout the data set, not just removing the first or last 60.000 rows. Is there a way to do this?
If it's to any help, my dataframe looks like this:

```
ID   username     text              date
1    @calr        lorem ipsum...    2012-05-05
2    @mart        lorem ipsum...    2012-05-05
3    @falk        lorem ipsum...    2012-05-05
4    @grif        lorem ipsum...    2012-05-05
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem

```
df[sample(nrow(df), 10000), ]
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
df[sample.int(70000, size = 10000),]
```